# JavaScript: Appending children to element

Tags: javascript, performance, dom

Which technique below is better from a user experience?

In both examples, assume that `thumbContainer` is set to the return value of `document.getElementById('thumbContainer')`, and `new Thumbnail(thumb).toXMLString()` returns a string with XHTML markup in it.

A) Simply `+=` with `thumbContainer.innerHTML`:

```
for (thumb in thumbnails) {
    thumbContainer.innerHTML += new Thumbnail(thumb).toXMLString();
}
```

B) Or converting `new Thumbnail(thumb).toXMLString()` to DOM elements and using `appendChild`?

```
for (thumb in thumbnails) {
    var shell = document.createElement('div');
    shell.innerHTML = new Thumbnail(thumb).toXMLString();
    for (i = 0; i < shell.childElementCount; i++) {
        thumbContainer.appendChild(shell.children[i]);
    }
}
```

I've used both and get complaints from Firefox that I've got a long-running script, and do I want to stop it?

Which loop is less-tight, that will allow the UI to update as new elements are added to the DOM?

Answer (score 10):

> A) Simply += with thumbContainer.innerHTML

**Never** do this. This has to serialise all the content to HTML, add a string to it, and parse it all back in. It's slow (doing it in a loop is particularly bad news) and it'll lose all JavaScript references, event handlers and so on.

IE's `insertAdjacentHTML` will do this more efficiently. It's also part of HTML5, but not widely implemented elsewhere yet.

> using appendChild?

Yes, that's fine. If you've got a *lot* of thumbs it will start to get slow (but not as bad as reparsing innerHTML each time). Making a DocumentFragment to insert multiple elements into the container child node list at once can help in some cases. Combining DocumentFragment with Range can do more still, but gets harder to write compatibly since IE's Range implementation is so StRange.

Either way, since you don't seem to be doing anything with the individual shell nodes, why not simply join all the thumbernail HTML strings together before parsing?

> for (var child in shell.childNodes) {

Don't use `for..in` on sequence types, it won't do what you think. It's only meant for use against `Object` used as a mapping. The correct way to iterate over an Array or NodeList is plain old `for (var i= 0; i<sequence.length; i++)`.

Comment: Thanks for the `insertAdjacentHTML`. That is what I needed

Answer (score 6):

Personally I like the second approach (using appendChild) better, because, you are adding new element to the document tree without affecting the old elements.

When using innerHTML += new content, you affect old content, because all the HTML has to be reassigned (replaced with new HTML that contains of old code and some new code).

But, if you want to increase the performance, I'd suggest using DocumentFragments. Using them you can append a whole set of nodes with just one appendChild call on the document tree. Worth reading: ["DOM DocumentFragments" by John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/), but it's not the case in your problem, because you get the content as a string, that you have to first convert to DOM nodes.

My second suggestion is, to create a string of HTML code and then use innerHTML on a temporary container to convert it to DOM nodes

```
var htmlCode = "";
for (thumb in thumbnails) {
    htmlCode += new Thumbnail(thumb).toXMLString();
}
var element = document.createElement(htmlCode);
element.innerHTML = htmlCode; // ... and append all the elements to document, or thumbContainer.innerHTML += htmlCode;
```

Comment: I would expect that your example doesn't work, since `Thumbnail#toXMLString` *returns a string with XHTML markup in it*. So, the provided tag name in `document.createElement(htmlCode)` is not a valid name.